# How to convert Character into Integer or Ascii value in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

**String id = "GJBR3I6R";**

> how to convert String id into integer or Ascii value ?

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following:

```dart
String id = "GJBR3I6R";
print(id.codeUnits);
```

Output:

```dart
[71, 74, 66, 82, 51, 73, 54, 82]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 import 'dart:convert';
 String id = "GJBR3I6R";
const asciiEncoder = AsciiEncoder();
print(AsciiEncoder().convert(id));
```

Output:

```
[71, 74, 66, 82, 51, 73, 54, 82]
```

for more information about how to convert string to its ASCII value refer to the below link
https://kodeazy.com/flutter-string-to-ascii/